# jquery toggle append remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a menu with submenu. I need that when I click on the submenu item, submenu text toggle beside menu item "Everyday". Like the image below [image]

```js
(function($) {
    $(".menu .sub-menu li a").each(function() {
        var dayName = $(this).text();
        $(this).on("click", function() {
            $(this).closest(".menu").children("li").children("a").append('<span class="day-name">' + dayName + '</span>');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu > li {
    position: relative;
}

.menu > li > a {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.menu .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    min-width: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.menu .sub-menu li {
}

.menu .sub-menu li a {
    color: #777;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Everyday</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sun</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tue</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wed</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Thu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fri</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is what I'm trying, but its does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function($) {
  $(".menu .sub-menu li a").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if (this.hasAttribute("data-selected")) {
      $this.removeAttr("data-selected");
    } else {
      $this.attr("data-selected", 'true');
    }

    $this.closest(".menu").find(" > li > a").html(fillButton);
  });

  function fillButton() {
    var options = $(this).next(".sub-menu").find("li a");
    if (options.filter("[data-selected]").length > 0) {
      if (options.length === options.filter("[data-selected]").length) {
        return "Every day";
      } else {
        var html = "Every ";
        options.filter("[data-selected]").each(function(i, el) {
          html += (i > 0) ? ", " + $(el).text() : $(el).text();
        });
        return html;
      }
    } else {
      return "Never";
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a[data-selected] {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
.menu > li {
  position: relative;
}
.menu > li > a {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.menu .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  min-width: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.menu .sub-menu li {} .menu .sub-menu li a {
  color: #777;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Never</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Sat</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sun</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Mon</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Tue</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Wed</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Thu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Fri</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm trying this and I got a problem, when i have multiple menu item and i clicked on submenu, submenu day pushed in every menu item, here it is https://jsfiddle.net/morshedx/y5e1hrpd/
how can i fixed this?

Comment: @MuhammadMorshed Make sure your selectors are correct. I fixed it here: https://jsfiddle.net/y5e1hrpd/1/

Comment: @MuhammadMorshed No problem. If this solved the issue, please mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javascript's [`join`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) & jQuery's - [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) & [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) methods with [`on('click')`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event like this:

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saumya04/Lgnh79kw/4/)

or see the code snippet below:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.menu .sub-menu li a').on('click', function(e) {
    
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    var txt = $('#title').text();
    var total_len = $('.menu .sub-menu li').length;
    var count = 0;
    var values = [];
    
    $('.menu .sub-menu li a.selected').each(function(i) {
      values.push($(this).text());
      count++;
    });
    
    if(count == total_len) {
      txt = "Every Day";
    } else {
      txt = "Every " + values.join(',');
    }
    $('#title').text(txt);

  });

})
```

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu > li {
    position: relative;
}

.menu > li > a {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.menu .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    min-width: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.menu .sub-menu li {
}

.menu .sub-menu li a {
    color: #777;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.menu .sub-menu li a.selected {
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a id="title" href="#">Every </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sun</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tue</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wed</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Thu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fri</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This does some redundant checking. Why the if-clause in each? You can filter the elements out earlier on.

Comment: @MuhammadMorshed - Why have you removed this as accepted answer! Is there any problem with this?

Comment: Probably because you don't listen to comments,  like mine.

Comment: @BramVanroy - If my answer is somewhat wrong, you may have edited the answer.

Comment: @MuhammadMorshed - Can you please check it again as I've optimized my code.

Comment: I'm so sorry for my late response :(

I've seen the demo and made your answer accepted without a test. When I'm trying your code I'm facing a problem which I mentioned Bram Vanroy's comments.

I also faced the same problem with Bram Vanroy's solution.
Then I'm commented on Bram Vanroy's solution with my problem and he makes it working.

I'm sorry again for my unexpected fault @SaumyaRastogi

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9s5y4a9/).

Change JS as below and add *schedule* class to the "Everyday" anchor.

```
(function($) {
  var currentValue = [];

  function renderValue(){
       var content = "Everyday ";

       $('.schedule').text(content + currentValue.join(' '));
  }    

  $(".menu .sub-menu li a").each(function() {
      var dayName = $(this).text();
      $(this).on("click", function() {
          var el = $(this),
            id = el.attr('data-id');

          currentValue[id] = currentValue[id] ? undefined : el.text();
          renderValue();
      });
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well. you will have to check if the appended span in the days list is equal to total days.

```js
(function($) {

  $(".menu").children("li").children("a.all").hide();

  $(".menu .sub-menu li a").each(function() {
    var dayName = $(this).text();

    $(this).on("click", function() {

      var li = $(this).closest(".menu").children("li");
      if ($(".menu .sub-menu li").length == $(".menu li a.days span").length + 1 && li.children("a.all").is(":visible") == false) {
        li.children("a.days").hide();
        li.children("a.all").show();
        li.children("a.days").append('<span class="day-name">, ' + dayName + '</span>');
      } else {
        li.children("a.all").hide();
        li.children("a.days").show();

        if (li.children("a.days").children("span:contains('" + dayName + "')").length == 0) {
          li.children("a.days").append('<span class="day-name">, ' + dayName + '</span>');
        } else {
          li.children("a.days").children("span:contains('" + dayName + "')").remove();
        }
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu > li {
  position: relative;
}
.menu > li > a {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.menu .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  min-width: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.menu .sub-menu li {} .menu .sub-menu li a {
  color: #777;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="days">Every</a>
    <a href="#" class="all">Everyday</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Sat</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sun</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Mon</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Tue</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Wed</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Thu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Fri</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```